# Match Data in 2 Cells and Replace with Data from a 3rd Cell (Excel)

Tags: excel, replace, match

Here is a basic explanation of what I am trying to do to accomplish some cleanup of product data on 100K+ rows of Excel data:

1. In sheet 1 if cell A1 matches data in any cell in Column B of sheet 2 then
2. Replace data in C1 of sheet 1 with contents of D1 from sheet 2

Basically I have an ID that is the same between sheet 1 and sheet 2, like a unique key.  When the ID match I just need to take the data in the adjacent cell and copy it from sheet 2 to sheet 1.

To further illustrate I have attached a couple example files. I would like to:

In the "destination" file I want to fill in the cell for short name and title if

The "Code" in column A from the "destination" matches column A in the "Source" then

Copy the data in column B and C (labeled short name and title).

I have tried VLookup with an if statement and Replace but can't get it to work. Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE Below**:

Thanks for the tips. Here is what I am trying that is returning a result but it isn't quite right. 
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$G$2:$G$6,1)=A2,H2)

I want use the ID in column A to lookup the same ID from Column D and return the value from column E into column B.  The ID could be in any row in column D.  In the screenshot below I have show where there are two errors in when I change the order in which the IDs appear.

[Screenshot with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCfZd.png)

Comment: **2. Replace data in C1 of sheet 1 with contents of D1 from sheet 2.** You sure not to pick the same row as it was found in column B at sheet 2? so if `Sheet1!A1` matches `Sheet2!B20` you still want `Sheet2!D1` at `Sheet1!C1`? going for `Sheet2!D20` would make more sense to me ?!?!

Comment: Looks like a basic VLookup. Would you post the one(s) you tried but did not work? Also, you should answer carefully the question of @DirkReichel, we need to understand your goal to better help.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `VLOOKUP` with `IF` clause